# Cli command to Install NGRX store in sub modules

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, lazy-loading, ngrx, store

In my project I have a lazy module and I want to create NGRX store folder under the sub module. So what is the cli command for creating the store along with actions, reducers and  effects under the sub folder ?

If I use the following, the store is created under App folder and app.module.ts in configured. I want to create the store folder under the folder 'X' which is under App folder and configure the x.module.ts file.

```
npm install @ngrx/{store,effects,entity,store-devtools} --save
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can use schematics (https://v8.ngrx.io/guide/schematics) to do so. Something like:

```
ng generate @ngrx/schematics:store State --root --module submodule/submodule.module.ts
```

Comment: Hi. it creates the submodule.effects.ts under the APP folder, I need to create under the app>subfolder>store folder. I used ng generate @ngrx/schematics: effect Subfolder --root --module submodule/submodule.module.ts

Comment: Here is an example to create effect in submodule from docs (https://v8.ngrx.io/guide/schematics/effect): `ng generate module User --flat false
ng generate effect user/User -m user.module.ts`. So it is like `submodule/effectName`, I think